# deployed but context failed to start - maven spring mvc project in netbeans IDE

Tags: spring-mvc

OK - Undeployed application at context path [/MavenSpringApp]
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Pravinkumar\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SpringMaven\target\MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FPRAVIN%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext932873472543407868.xml&path=/MavenSpringApp
FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/MavenSpringApp] but context failed to start